# Showing a Set is a Partition of Another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Here's a homework question I'm probably over thinking.

Prove that if $S$ is a set and $A$ is a nonempty proper subset of $S$, then $\Pi = \{A,S\setminus A\} $ is a partition of $S$.

The claim is clearly true, however I'm having difficulty structuring my proof. I believe that if $\{A, S\setminus A\}$ is partition of $S$, then $A \cup S\setminus A = S$ and $A \cap S\setminus A = \emptyset$.

Is showing these conditions are true all that required to prove the statement above, or is there something I'm missing? Thank you.

---

After looking back at the definition used in our textbook,

> Let $S$ be a nonempty set. A **partition** $\Pi$ of $S$ is a family of 
>   $\Pi = \{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of nonempty subsets of $S$ satisfying these conditions:
>
> 1) $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i = S$,
>
> 2) $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$.

It's clear to me now that to prove something is a partition of a set, you can simply prove these two conditions are true.

Comment: What **definition** of "partition" are you using?  The simplest way to prove something is "X" is to show that it satisfies the definition of "A".

Comment: This is fine, since A is a nonempty proper subset of S.